# NanoBSD: issue including firmware for ral driver in image

Tags: freebsd, firmware

With my current NanoBSD build I'm not able to bring up the ral0 interface. Instead I get the following:

```
...
rt2561sfw: could not load firmware image, error 2
ral0: rt2661_load_microcode: unable to retrieve firmware image rt2561sfw
ral0: rt2661_init_locked: could not load 8051 microcode, error 22
```

I figured out that I need the firmware for the device which I hoped accomplishing with ral and ralfw modules in my nanobsd.conf file:

```
NANO_NAME="nano"

NANO_KERNEL=GENERIC
NANO_ARCH=i386
TARGET_ARCH=i386; export TARGET_ARCH
TARGET_CPUTYPE=i386; export TARGET_CPUTYPE
NO_CLEAN=YES
NANO_DRIVE=ad1

NANO_MEDIASIZE=1900000
NANO_CONFSIZE=40960
NANO_RAM_ETCSIZE=20480
NANO_RAM_TMPVARSIZE=102400
NANO_NEWFS="-m 0 -b 4096 -f 512 -i 8192 -O1"
# NANO_PMAKE="make -j 8"
NANO_PMAKE="${NANO_PMAKE} -DDB_FROM_SRC"
NANO_MODULES="pf pflog if_bridge bridgestp netgraph/netgraph netgraph/ether netgraph/pppoe netgraph/socket wlan wlan_xauth wlan_tkip wlan_ccmp wlan_wep wlan_rssadapt firmware amdtemp bios wlan_amrr ral ralfw"

# 0 -> Leave second image all zeroes so it compresses better.
# 1 -> Initialize second image with a copy of the first
NANO_INIT_IMG2=0


CONF_INSTALL='
WITHOUT_INSTALLLIB=yes
WITHOUT_TOOLCHAIN=yes
'

CONF_WORLD='
WITHOUT_ACCT=yes
WITHOUT_ACPI=yes
WITHOUT_AMD=yes
WITHOUT_APM=yes
WITHOUT_AT=yes
WITHOUT_ATM=yes
WITHOUT_AUDIT=yes
WITHOUT_AUTHPF=yes
WITHOUT_BLUETOOTH=yes
WITHOUT_CALENDAR=yes
WITHOUT_CDDL=yes
WITHOUT_CTM=yes
WITHOUT_CVS=yes
WITHOUT_DICT=yes
WITHOUT_EXAMPLES=yes
WITHOUT_FDT=yes
WITHOUT_FLOPPY=yes
WITHOUT_FREEBSD_UPDATE=yes
WITHOUT_GAMES=yes
WITHOUT_GCOV=yes
WITHOUT_GPIB=yes
WITHOUT_GPIO=yes
WITHOUT_INFO=yes
WITHOUT_IPFILTER=yes
WITHOUT_IPFW=yes
WITHOUT_IPX=yes
WITHOUT_JAIL=yes
WITHOUT_LOCALES=yes
WITHOUT_LOCATE=yes
WITHOUT_LPR=yes
WITHOUT_NDIS=yes
WITHOUT_NIS=yes
WITHOUT_NLS=yes
WITHOUT_NLS_CATALOGS=yes
WITHOUT_NS_CACHING=yes
WITHOUT_PC_SYSINSTALL=yes
WITHOUT_PORTSNAP=yes
WITHOUT_PROFILE=yes
WITHOUT_QUOTAS=yes
WITHOUT_RCMDS=yes
WITHOUT_RCS=yes
WITHOUT_ROUTED=yes
WITHOUT_SHAREDOCS=yes
WITHOUT_SOURCELESS=yes
WITHOUT_SYSINSTALL=yes
WITHOUT_USB=yes
WITHOUT_MAN=yes
WITHOUT_MAN_UTILS=yes
'

cust_local() {
        echo '
sshd_enable=YES
ifconfig_re0="DHCP"
' >>${NANO_WORLDDIR}/etc/rc.conf
}

customize_cmd cust_pkg
customize_cmd cust_comconsole
customize_cmd cust_install_files
customize_cmd cust_allow_ssh_root
customize_cmd cust_local
```

However this leads to the kernel failing to install, more specifically I get the following error

```
===> ral (install)
install -o root -g wheel -m 555   if_ral.ko /usr/obj/nanobsd.nano//_.w/boot/kernel
install -o root -g wheel -m 555   if_ral.ko.symbols /usr/obj/nanobsd.nano//_.w/boot/kernel
===> ralfw (install)
===> ralfw/rt2561 (install)
install -o root -g wheel -m 555   rt2561fw.ko /usr/obj/nanobsd.nano//_.w/boot/kernel
install: rt2561fw.ko: No such file or directory
*** Error code 71
```

I Googled around but didn't find anything useful. I guess that this is basic FreeBSD module building stuff... but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the source is there waiting for me to simply read it and so I found this interesting entry in **/usr/src/sys/modules/Makefile** :

```
.if ${MK_SOURCELESS_UCODE} != "no"
_bce=           bce
_fatm=          fatm
_fxp=           fxp
_ispfw=         ispfw
_mwlfw=         mwlfw
_ralfw=         ralfw
_sf=            sf
_sn=            sn
_ti=            ti
_txp=           txp
.endif
```

Which seems to control whether the ral firmware (and a bunch of other firmwares) is included in the kernel. (read the rest of the file for the details).

So I figured that setting the following in the nanobsd.conf would solve all misery:

```
CONF_BUILD='
MK_SOURCELESS_UCODE=yes
'
```

Strangely now the build-world (not build-kernel!) fails with:

```
--- buildworld ---
make[1]: "/usr/src/share/mk/bsd.own.mk" line 457: MK_SOURCELESS_UCODE can't be set by a user.
*** [buildworld] Error code 1
```

which deserves a thread on its own.

Anyway, when trying:

```
CONF_BUILD='
_ralfw=ralfw
'
```

things do seem to work out the way I wanted.

I haven't been able to load the new image on the device in question, but the install log this time shows the **ralfw** module being installed.

The issue is fixed, but I'm still interested in an explanation of someone with a clear view on all this.

Comment: Just loaded the NanoBSD image on the device and the ral0 driver now works as expected